# How quality relates to functionality? (it is not considered by quality models)

Tags: test-design, standards, quality-assessment

Some quality models, like the probably best known one, ISO 25000 (SQuaRE project) defines quality model based on quality characteristics that are all non-functional. It explicitly reads that the model is not intended to evaluate functional aspects of software.

I get it - if something works as expected (e.g. a stapler) you cannot really decide about its quality until you assess non-functional aspects like its material, ergonomy, durability etc.

But at the same time, if the stapler does not work, no amount of non-functional requirements could make up for it.

In addition, the ISO standard defines quality as follows:

> degree to which the software product satisfies stated and implied
>   needs when used under specified conditions

So it is meant to be used in conjunction with functional assessment? IF the model itself does not deal with FR, how can I decide whether or not the software satisfies the needs?

Answer (score 3):

To improve quality for a software product we are splitting up quality into internal and external quality. Spread over three quality groups. It gives a more detailed view on the different quality aspects that are relevant in software development.

External quality determines *the fulfillment of stakeholder requirements* and internal quality determines *the ability to move forward on a project*.

Functional Quality

- Meeting the specified requirements.
- Creating software that has few defects.
- Good enough performance.
- Ease of learning and ease of use.

Process Quality

- Meeting delivery dates.
- Meeting budgets.
- A repeatable development process that reliably delivers quality software.

Structural Quality

- Code testability.
- Code maintainability.
- Code understandability.
- Code efficiency.
- Code security.

Sources with more details:

- http://www.davidchappell.com/writing/white_papers/The_Three_Aspects_of_Software_Quality_v1.0-Chappell.pdf
- https://meekrosoft.wordpress.com/2010/10/31/internal-and-external-software-quality/